# How can I send Magento invoices automatically?

Tags: email, magento, transactional

I want to know how I let Magento send an order confirmation/invoice automatically after a customer placed an order. I know how I send an email manually but I want that customers get an email automatically after placing an order.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I am using magento 1.9.3

Answer (score -1):

```
Magento 1.9+ relies completely on cron jobs to send emails.
Set up cron tasks in the Magento admin under System > Configuration > Advanced > System > Cron
```